# Spliting values in sql with single query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I found following query on internet for spiting data from "-".
I want only value after "-" how can I achieve that. And also i need max of that value

Can anyone help me with it.

```
SELECT 
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Certs
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(BATCH_NO,'-','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   BATCH
)BATCH
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

Sample Data

```
Batch_NO
----------------
30-002
30-002
001-003
```

output

```
-------------
30
002
30
002
001
003
```

Comment: Here is some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I required value right of "-" and did it with following code.

Thanks every one who help me.

```
select MAX(RIGHT(BATCH_NO, charindex('-',REVERSE(BATCH_NO))-1)) AS BATCH_NO FROM BATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `INT` or any numeric datatype in `value` method instead of `varchar` datatype

```
SELECT Max(m.n.value('.[1]', 'INT')) AS Certs
FROM   (SELECT Cast('<XMLRoot><RowData>'
                    + Replace(BATCH_NO, '-', '</RowData><RowData>')
                    + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
        FROM   (VALUES ( '30-002'),
                       ('30-002'),
                       ('001-003')) tc (batch_no))BATCH
       CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

Comment: I need only value after "-" not all the value (right of hi fen)

Comment: @Lord_of_Lucifer - Replace table valued constructor with your table